# Why can't I center my navigation?

Tags: html, css

Okay, so I centered my navigation in one of my themes, but for some reason I cannot replicate the same effect even when I copied and pasted the code.

This is my website http://goo.gl/WSfOzw

I have tried various combinations of using **display: inline-block**, **margin: 0 auto**, and **text-align: center** but nothing seems to work at the moment.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The reason it's not working is because you are setting the width of the ul to `100%` If you just change that to `auto` it will work.

```
.main-navigation ul {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding-left: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto; /* CHANGE THIS LINE */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the list item's `float: left` property and add `display: inline-block` to the list items like this:

```
.main-navigation li {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Also, you don't need any of the current properties of your `ul` so remove all of them (including the width: 100%):

```
.main-navigation ul  {
  list-style: none; <<-- REMOVE THIS
  margin: 0 auto; <<-- REMOVE THIS
  padding-left: 0; <<-- REMOVE THIS
  text-align: center; <<-- REMOVE THIS
  width: 100%; <<-- REMOVE THIS
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Give your menu class a with of 100% then give your .main-navigation ul a set width.

```
.main{
width:100%;
}
```

and get rig of this the width in:

```
.main-navigation ul
```